# How to change logback config on android after the apk is deployed? without recompiling

Tags: android, logback

In regular Java, it's possible to put an alternate `logback.xml` file in the folder of the `jar` to change the `logback` config (e.g., to change the log level).

Is this possible on Android with `logback-android`?

Comment: I gues your pick is this: http://www.acra.ch

Comment: Or you can do a trick. If your purpose is logging any kind of interactions then you can create a log file which you can send in background, or maintain a log in your database by calling web services

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. [`logback-android`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android#initialization-search-path) allows specifying an alternate/optional location in addition to the regular location in your `logback.xml`.

In the example configs below, `logback-android` loads the `logback-debug.xml` file only if the file exists. Otherwise, it loads `logback-release.xml`.

#### assets/logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <includes>
    <!-- logback picks first configuration found in the following list -->
    <include resource="assets/config/logback-debug.xml"/>
    <include resource="assets/config/logback-release.xml"/>
  </includes>
</configuration>
```

#### assets/config/logback-debug.xml

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

#### assets/config/logback-release.xml

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/data/data/com.example/files/log/foo.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why doesn't logback-debug.xml exist in release build? Why can't we just separate configuration files to "src/debug/assets/logback.xml" for debug version and src/main/assets/logback.xml for release version?

Comment: @KyryloZapylaiev Yes, that's another way to do it *only at build time*. The OP is requesting a location that `logback` automatically reads after the app is already deployed (e.g.,  a known directory on the SD card) that can override the default `logback.xml`. While this answer specifies internal paths in `assets` as alternate locations, the location could alternatively be in the host filesystem or a remote URL.